# If my p-value is greater than the critical value can I assume both distributions are similar?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, classification, p-value

I have trained a binary classier and have tested it based on a validation set and confirmed those results on a test set. I was wanting to show that both the validation and test set show similar results although I'm a little unsure if my approach was correct.

I calculated a difference in proportions for the True Acceptance and True Rejection rate as shown below for both the test and validation set. I then determine the Z-score, please note the below is repeated for both the true acceptance and true rejection rates.

$$
 ese_{Test-Validation} =\sqrt{\frac{p_{test}(1-p_{test})}{n_{test}} + \frac{p_{Validation}(1-p_{Validation})}{n_{Validation}}}
$$

$$
Z = \frac{p_{test} - p_{validation}}{ese_{Test-Validation}}
$$

Then from the above Z score I can calculate a p value. My initial logic was that if the p value is > 0.05 then the test and validation set are similar but I'm not entirely sure if that is correct to make such a statement or not?

I have also recently became aware of the Delongs method for comparing ROC curves which I think I would probably prefer to use although I feel I need to confirm the above logic is correct.

Comment: If what amounts to a binomial proportions test does not give low enough $p$-value, you would presumably fail to reject the null hypothesis that the two proportions are the same.  This could be because the proportions are indeed very close or that you did not have enough data to distinguish them.  Whether that is enough to say "accept the null hypothesis they are the same" is more a question of philosophy and language than of statistics

Comment: I think what made me concerned is during my stats lectures they use very specific language (and made a point of it) that you either reject the null hypothesis or fail to reject it which gave me some feeling there was something I was missing in terms of a binary choice of either accept it or not.

Comment: No. Only that your data do not show a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

You went looking for a difference and did not find one. You now want to claim that there is no difference.

> Well how hard did you look?

If you do not find something but did not look hard, then your claim that the something is not there is a weak one. If you did look hard, then your claim that the something is not there means more.

In hypothesis testing, test [power](/questions/tagged/power) is what quantifies how hard you looked for a difference. Power depends on the difference you want to find. If you have high power to find a difference of $\delta$ and do not find a difference, you can start to make claims about there not being a difference of $\delta$ or more.

Until you quantify how hard you looked by considering your test power, however, you cannot make strong conclusions about distribution similarity.

A standard claim is that an absence of evidence (high p-value) is not evidence of absence. However, if you looked hard for evidence (high power) and still have an absence of evidence, then you have a stronger case for that absence.